# I want to keep a function running continuously in my Winform C# project, until the form window is closed

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010

I want to keep a function running continuously in my Winform C# project, until the form window is closed. I don't want to put it in a very long timer and call it again and again. What shall I do?

I need something like this to keep validating if the form is open or closed continuously:

```
while(this.close() == false)
{
 my_func();
}
```

the above code is certainly wrong but I wrote that to give you an idea as to what I want.

Comment: put while(true) on a thread?, seems extremely inefficient though, can I ask what the purpose is?

Comment: If you do that make sure the thread is marked as background or it will keep the exe open after you close the main form.

Comment: And why would not put it in a very long timer? You'll end up using all your CPU and freezing the window anyway.

Comment: Sounds like a job for a Windows Service.

Comment: If you do this without putting it in a background thread, your application will not properly respond to the user interface. There are lots of c# threading posts here on SO. Do a search for `[c#] background thread` or `[c#] multi thread`.

Comment: yes Ken... its not efficient to put it in a background thread...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I came with this idea, as it doesn't consumes CPU much and runs efficiently, though I was trying to avoid the timer, but it seems to be an easiest choice:

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    timer.Start();
}
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   my_func();
}
```

and we can set the timer's interval property to a small value like 200 millisecond or something, so the `my_func()` runs almost continuously, until the form is closed.

Comment: Why would you be trying to avoid using a timer? This appears to do exactly what you want. At least to the extent we can tell from the limited information provided in the question.

Comment: because I thought that there must some already existing method that continuously keep the form validating, and it might solve the purpose... but I realized that timer works just perfect in this scenario.! :)

Answer (score 4):

Remember there are FormClosing and FormClosed events that you can utilize on the form.

Handling one of those would be about a billion times more efficient than continuously polling for the form's status...

Comment: the FormClosing and FormClosed events don't keep on validating the form continuously... It doesn't work..!

Comment: i don't understand why 4 people liked ur answer even though its of no use, and nothing new...